# Jquery GET Function does not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, telerik-grid

jQuery GET function does not execute.

I am using a Telerik Data grid that executes the following script when a row is selected

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onRowSelected(e) {
    IPAddressId = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    var dialogDiv = $('#result');
    var viewUrl = '/IPAddresses/Edit/' + IPAddressId;
    $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
        alert(viewUrl);
    });
};
</script>
```

I have the alert inside the .get function for testing. I actually have other code I will place in there.

If I place the alert(viewUrl) above the $.get function, the alert displays however as it is shown above the alert does not get displayed.

Comment: is there a particular reason you didn't use `var IPAddressId `?, I know this is not the problem, but I am curious

Comment: Are you sure the http requests works? As in, if you put the alert outside (so things work) then you copy that address into your browser bar, you will get the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $.get is correct.

It's possible you are getting a 500 error, and you didn't specify an error function to get called, so you never see it. Open your console (Firebug, Chrome Developer tools, etc) and go to the 'net panel'. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

The `function(data){ alert( viewUrl ) }` is a callback function . It will be excuted when the ajax request obtain the server correct response .

So you should debug this, use firefox's firebug extension ，or use chrome developer tool. Watch the newwork panel , and lookup this request , is it have been responsed with http code "200"?